# Looking for a way to disable special handling of CSS on IE8 over an RDP connection?

Tags: html, internet-explorer-8, remote-desktop

I'm currently working on a website, and when I test the website locally, everything looks fine, but when I test the website over an RDP connection to the *same machine* the styles handling is all jacked around.  The fonts are all fixed height, the browser settings haven't changed, I just refreshed the page after I reconnected over RDP.

**Here's what it looks like Locally**:

[image: Local Example]

**Here's what it looks like over RDP**

(to the same machine, same browser, same session, just refreshed):

[image]

**Is there some sort of HTML metadata I can add that will prevent this behavior?**

This isn't the only example, this is a site-wide issue. I can, of course, go through and try to shoehorn everything to work a little better over an RDP connection, in most instances, I'm just hoping there's a less time-consuming fix.

Comment: I don't think this has anything to do with RDP as such. Has the resolution of your connection changed in between?

Comment: No, the resolution was identical. As in the resolution of the Remote Desktop Session is the same.

Comment: Also this website has been tested at multiple resolutions on multiple browsers without seeing this behavior. The only time this behavior is seen is with IE8 over RDP.

Comment: +1 MvanGeest - It was IE7 Standards mode vs IE8 Standards mode... which is odd, because like I said, all I did was walk to another machine, and remote into my machine then hit refresh.

Comment: IE8 Mode fixes the issue. Is there any way to force it to IE8 standards mode?

Comment: No idea. It's probably the other way round: "what's forcing it to revert to IE7 standards mode?" Maybe some Internet Zone setting?

Comment: Possibly, but I'm more concerned about people whose machines I can't control browsing to the site in IE8 but getting shown IE7 rendered stuff.  (Regardless it looks like I need to fix some things for IE7)

Comment: Thank you MvanGeest, for pointing me in the right direction, I've posted my fix below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Added the tag:

```
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
```

To my  in my HTML.  This forced IE to use the latest version of IE standards. (in this case IE8)... without that it was reverting to IE7 Standards mode for some reason.

Thank you to MvanGeest for pointing me in the right direction.

The fact it looked messed up in IE7 Standards mode does mean I'll have to revisit my CSS and put in some fixes, but the above solved the issue at least for IE8 browsers.

Strange that only over RDP was it defaulting the mode to IE7 Standards mode.